DC-DC converter to make variable output +/-70V from 5V input
This is a SEPIC DC-DC architecture from Texas Instruments to make a variable output from +/-5V to +/-70V. Iwould like to understand the principle of how the negative voltage is being made from the positive node by this part of the circuit.


I won't dive into details so I'll leave a simple explanation here: You have a pulsating voltage with a non-zero DC offset and it's coming from the L1-Q1 junction. You remove the DC offset via C25 or C35, now you have a pulsating AC (i.e. no DC offset). Then you allow either positive or negative sections to pass through and this is done by the diodes D3 and D6: D3 allows positive peaks, D6 allows negative peaks (look how they are placed).

@Rohat Kılıç thanks for the nice explanation, it was very clear, the only thing that I did not understand is how D6 allows negative peaks?

Its cathode is connected to the ground. That should give you a hint. What should be the voltage at the anode in order for the D6 to be in conduction?
